# Network Security and Encryption explained in laymen terms

Tags: networking

Although I might pretend very well that I know a thing about networks or security and it might help me pass an interview or fix a bug, I don't really feel I'm fooling anyone.
I'm looking for laymen explanation of current network security concepts and solutions. The information is scattered around and I didn't find a resource for "dummies" like me (e.g experienced Java developers that can speak the jargon but have no real clue what it means).

Topics I have a weak notion about and want to understand better as a Java developer:

- PGP
- Public / Private keys
- RSA / DES
- SSL and 2 way SSL (keystore / trustore)
- Protecting against Man in the middle fraud
- Digital Signature and Certificates

Is there a resource out there that really explains it in a way that doesn't require a Cisco certificate / Linux lingo / know what is subnet masking or other plumbing skills?

Comment: It seems you want to learn more about encryption, not necessarily network-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book [Cryptography Engineering](http://www.schneier.com/book-ce.html) by Ferguson, Schneier, and Kohno might be something that would get you a decent way down the road to understanding the topics you listed.  I read the first version of this book (*Practical Cryptography*) and found it to be quite good. For example, I thought the descriptions of public key/private key cryptography to be reasonably straightforward to understand.

It might not explicitly describe the specific terms in all cases that you are asking about. For example, I just looked in the index of my copy of *Practical Cryptography* and do not see the terms "keystore" and "truststore", but the first google hit I clicked on for those provided a definition in language I understood (largely because I read the book).

I also own *Applied Cryptography* mentioned by Aidan Cully, and I think it is also a very good book and certainly worth owning.  However I tend to think of it more as a reference book (although somewhat dated - the copyright is 1996). In terms of real-word advice, though, I think the original title of the newer book *Practical Cryptography* was right on.  The book seems, well, practical.

Answer (score 1):

Schneier's [Applied Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471117099) is how I learned most of what I know.  I haven't read it, but expect Ross Anderson's [Security Engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470068523) would also be a good resource.

Answer (score 1):

[Priactical UNIX and Internet Security](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565921481) will cover a lot of that stuff and give you a basic UNIX background. Also, if you have extra time [Academic Earth](http://www.academicearth.org/lectures/search/security/) has free video lectures from top universities.